Looking for a sigmoid-like function that can be parameterized to have infinite slope at inflection point
I currently need a function that has the standard properties of being a sigmoid, i.e. $y\to\pm L$ as $x\to\pm \infty$, but also has a parameter that allows for $y'\to \infty$ as $x\to 0$ without creating a discontinuity. In a way, the function might behave like $y=\sqrt[3]{x}$ around $x=0$ but otherwise be asymptotic like a standard sigmoid. Also, this should be a single function and not a piecewise function.
EDIT: Piecewise is fine if the definition still provides a $C^\infty$ function (everywhere except the part with the infinite slope). Piecewise discontinuous is what I need to avoid.
It might look a bit like this:


Do you consider the absolute value function, $|x|$, and signum function, $\operatorname{sign}(x)$, as piecewise functions?

It's easy to come up with a piecewise function. Otherwise it's hard.

@AdamRubinson If there are no known (or at least commonly known) classes of functions that meet my requirements, then I would entertain a piecewise function that is at least $C^2$

Well, the function I was thinking of was $\arctan(\sqrt{x}).$

Yes, that is certainly in the direction of what I'm looking for

Both $\text{arctan}(x)^{\frac{1}{3}}$ (in blue) and $\text{arctan}\left(x^{\frac{1}{3}}\right)$ (in red) provide the behaviour you're after. I'm sure there are also many others, allowing you to customise speed of convergence to asymptotes, etc., if that is desired.

